# Matrix Decomposition with restriction on eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $B$ be an invertible $n\times n$ complex matrix. Prove that there exist $n\times n$ complex matrices
$A, C$ such that the following three conditions are satisfied simultaneously:

- (i) $B = AC$
- (ii) $A$ is diagonalizable, and $1$ is the only eigenvalue of
  $C$; and
- (iii) $AC=CA$

I am stumped by the condition that $1$ should be the only eigenvalue of $C$. How to find a matrix $C$ that fulfills this condition? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just in case this is what you're missing, that is equivalent to requesting $\det\left (C-Ix\right) =(1-x)^n$. I'll have a deeper look at it in the morning

Comment: Take $\mathbf{C}$ as Identity.

Comment: hi @Sudarsan if you take C to be identity, then A=B. How would you guarantee B is diagonalizable? Not all invertible matrices are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** If $B$ is a single invertible Jordan block, we may choose $C=\frac1\lambda B$ and $A=\lambda I$.

Comment: Hi @user1551 the condition at the beginning of problem states that B is an invertible n by n complex matrix.

Comment: @user112835 OK. See my new edit.

Comment: Thanks @user1551 for the hint. I can solve the question now. So basically we convert B to its Jordan block and multiply the Jordan block with another diagonal matrix containing the reciprocal of the eigenvalues of B to get C, right?

Comment: @user112835 Yes. And after converting $B$ back to its original form, $A$ may be no longer *diagonal*. Yet it is always *diagonalisable*.